# Continue working on the command line after finishing from tkinter GUI in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, command-line

I am trying to create a simple script, but making a login for it using tkinter, whenever the username and password are entered correctly its supposed to close the tkinter window and go to the shell the command line code and the tkinter code is all in the same .py file, the problem is whenever I try that using classes python goes straight into the CLI code, ignoring the tkinter completely.

```
from tkinter import *
class CLI():
    def something():
        eg = input("name: ")
        print("your name is",eg)
    something()
def login():
    if (txtUsername.get() == "admin" and txtPassword.get() == "secret"):
        messagebox.showinfo("Access granted", "Valid")
        c = CLI()
        print(c)
        top.destroy()
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Access denied", "Invalid")


top = Tk()
top.wm_title("example")
top.minsize(width=500, height=400)
top.resizable(width=False, height=False)
var = StringVar()
lblUsername = Label(top, text="Username:")
lblUsername.pack()
txtUsername = Entry(top)
txtUsername.pack()
lblPassword = Label(top, text="Password:")
lblPassword.pack()
txtPassword = Entry(top)
txtPassword.pack()
btnCHKLogin = Button(top, text="Check Login..", command=login)
btnCHKLogin.pack()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you call `something()` immediately after defining it, rather than after the `tkinter` code has run:

```
def something():
    eg = input("name: ")
    print("your name is",eg)
something() #you call something() here so it executes first
```

Removing this line will allow the tkinter code to run.

Comment: but how will I be able to call the function if I remove it?

Comment: You only need to remove the call to something() here, not the actual function

Comment: Yeah, but if i remove that line, I wont be able to use that function, I will only be able to get the login screen..

Comment: because it is part of `class CLI`, you can call it later with `CLI.something()`

Comment: the code above is only an example, I will need the whole class which might contain more than one function, and please forgive me as I am new to python.

Comment: you should still be able to do it like this

Comment: if not, what problems are you encountering?

Comment: cant I call the class as a whole new .py file instead of calling each function in the class?

Comment: when you say "call the class", what do you mean? you can import the file containing the class, but need to call the methods in it individually

Comment: as if you're calling a function `something()` but class instead

Comment: if you mean `CLI()`, no you cannot do this. You can create an instance of it, `x = CLI()`, but still need to call each method separately:`x.something()`

Comment: if you are new to python, you may find it useful to read the documentation on classes https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: well its not really needed, just makes things a little bit easier, however calling each function inside the class works just great, the only thing now I'm getting wrong is random 'None's but I'm thinking that's easy to solve, I really appreciate your help thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks, happy to help

Comment: the random 'None's I been getting were because of this 
`fTwo = CLI.function2()
print(fTwo)`
I thought this how it works, but looks like `print(fTwo)` was not needed.